# MLE for the maximum of n values that are observed only with noise

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, extreme-value

Suppose $x_1, ..., x_n$ is a fixed set of real numbers. Let $\epsilon_1, ..., \epsilon_n \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ be i.i.d. with known $\sigma^2$, and suppose we get to observe only $z_i = x_i + \epsilon_i$, $i=1, ..., n$. What is the MLE of $\max(x_1, ..., x_n)$?

Comment: Intuitively, it should be $\max(z_1,...,z_n).$ The question is how to show this. I'm working on an answer now.

Comment: @dlnB is right; it follows from invariance of MLE. https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/459605/119261

Comment: Got it! See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easiest to think of $(x_1,...,x_n)$ as parameters and $(z_1,...,z_n)$ as data. Then the joint likelihood function is 
$$L(x_1,...,x_n|z_1,...,z_n) =  \prod_{i=1}^n \phi(\frac{z_i-x_i}{\sigma}),$$
and joint log-likelihood function is 
$$\ell(x_1,...,x_n|z_1,...,z_n) =  \sum_{i=1}^n \ln \phi(\frac{z_i-x_i}{\sigma}),$$
Solving the first-order conditions gives MLE estimator $\hat{x_i}=z_i$ for $i=1,...,n$.

The invariance property of MLE says if $\hat{\theta}$ is the MLE estimator of $\theta$, then for any $f(\theta)$, the MLE estimator is $f(\hat{\theta})$. It follows that the MLE estimator of $\max(x_1,...,x_n)$ is $\max(\hat{x_1},...,\hat{x_n}) = \max(z_1,...,z_n).$

Comment: Interesting. I guess this could become intuitive if I were to understand the invariance property. Anyhow this is an impressively biased MLE when n > 1.

Comment: Very interesting that this is biased. How did you find this?

Comment: Consider the edge case where all the x's are 0. $E(max(z_1, ..., z_n))$ is then just the expectation of the maximum of n Gaussians, which is strictly positive for n > 1: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/89037/262048 . This does not contradict your answer though

Comment: Clever. Nice observation.

Comment: The proof is simpler when the function $\tau(\cdot)$ is 1-1, but the theorem holds for any function $\tau(\cdot)$. See Casella (1990): Theorem 7.2.1 (Invariance Property of Maximum Likelihood Estimators): If $\hat{\theta}$ is the MLE of $\theta$, then for any function $\tau (\theta)$, the MLE of $\tau(\theta)$ is $\tau(\hat{\theta})$.

Comment: this MLE appears to be an example of an MLE that is not consistent -- would you agree with that? As $n \to \infty$, this MLE diverges to infinity. But ... wait a second, there is no way to compute that limit without assuming some kind of generating model for the x's. So confused. Is there something fundamentally inconsistent about calling the x's "parameters" in this case?

Comment: Great points. But does it make sense to let $n \to \infty$ in this case? I am thinking about something like a regression framework where we don’t know the values of the $\beta$ vector but know it’s length and want to estimate $\max \{\beta_1,...,\beta_k\}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107408/discussion-between-zkurtz-and-dlnb).